# How can I return ModelandView file and string?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Is it possible to get return object and string in js?

```
  Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();

   if (preview.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")) {
         myModel.put("IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION", Boolean.FALSE);
         myModel.put("format", "pdf");
        //return new ModelAndView("returnOnReleasedConsignment", myModel);
    }else if (preview.equalsIgnoreCase("xls")) {
        myModel.put("IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION", Boolean.TRUE);
        myModel.put("format", "xls");

        myModel.put("checking", "true");
    }
  return new ModelAndView("returnOnReleased", myModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add add a String to the model.

```
String myString = "hello";
myModel.put("myString", myString);
```

and you can add an Object to it as well. It is a hashmap.
    Object myObject = new Object();
    myModel.put("myObject", myObject);

Comment: I tried before, that the script i tried. It cannot get any result for getting this 
   
myModel.put("checking", "true");